# Facebook Login from Nested Fragment not working - Activity result fragment index out of range

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, onactivityresult, android-nested-fragment

My app structure is as follows

MainActivity(A ViewPager which contains 2 fragments - Fragment 1 and Fragment 2)

```
| 
|--Fragment 1
|         (ViewPager with several fragments which is an     
|          app tutorial/intro)
|
|--Fragment 2
          (Single Fragment where I have my custom facebook login button)
```

At first, my onActivityResult for the nested fragment was not getting called. But I found a solution to that using the following code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult");
    List<Fragment> frags = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (frags != null) {
        for (Fragment f : frags) {
            if (f != null)
                handleResult(f, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}

private void handleResult(Fragment frag, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (frag instanceof LoginFragment) { // custom interface with no signitures
        frag.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    List<Fragment> frags = frag.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (frags != null) {
        for (Fragment f : frags) {
            if (f != null)
                handleResult(f, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Now my onActivityResult in my LoginFragment does get called, however I do not login.
This is my onActivityResult for the LoginFragment

```
   @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "LoginFragment onActivityResult");
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I have also registered a callback using

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback but my OnSuccess callback is not hit.
```

Instead I get a log stating the following

```
W/FragmentActivity﹕ Activity result fragment index out of range: 0x2face
D/MainActivity﹕ onActivityResult
D/LoginFragment﹕ LoginFragment onActivityResult
```

How do I make sure Login happens successfully and the callbacks work?

EDIT : On debugging this issue, I kept a break point in the onActivityResult callback of the FragmentActivity class.

```
if (mFragments.mActive == null || index < 0 || index >= mFragments.mActive.size()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Activity result fragment index out of range: 0x"
                    + Integer.toHexString(requestCode));
            return;
        }
```

mFragments.mActive == null is false.

index< 0 is false

index >= mFragments.mActive.size()  is true

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for getting called `onActivityResult` when activity receives it:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    for (Fragment fragment : getActiveFragments()) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Thanks..!!

Comment: This did not work. Like I've mentioned, the onActivityResult in my nested fragment IS CALLED. That is not the issue. The problem is that my loginManager callbacks are not being called .

Comment: @Rohan : Can you debug it ??

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out.

I was trying to login from my nested fragment using

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this,Arrays.asList
("public_profile", "user_friends"));
```

Instead, what I needed to do was pass the activity instead of the fragment to the logInWithReadPermissions method.

Therefore, the correct way to login in this case is

```
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(getActivity(),           
Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
```